# Error using fmincon (line 300) A must have 'n' column(s)

Tags: matlab, optimization

I'm getting the error "Error using fmincon (line 300) A must have 'n' column(s)." when trying to solve the following optimisation code. I think there is an error in the definition of the constraints. Someone had the same problem http://goo.gl/35MeC but unfortunately I don't read chinese!!

The objective is to find the optimal values of the array Y subject to constraints on Y and on its integral IntY. To understand better the nature of the problem, each value of Y represent the value of a variable in a successive time step, and the objective function to minimise is basically a cost of interactions.

```
function [Y, IntY] = optTest()
    % inputs of the problem
    TS        = 10;   % number of time steps
    YMin      = -0.1; % minimum value of Y
    YMax      = 0.2;  % maximum value of Y
    IntYMin   = 0.1;  % min value of the integral of Y
    IntYMax   = 0.9;  % max value of the integral of Y
    IntYInit  = 0.2;  % initial value of the integral of Y
    Prices    = PricesFun(TS);

    % use of function 'fmincon', preparation of the inputs
    % x = fmincon(fun,x0,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub)
    A = [tril(ones(TS))*1;tril(ones(TS))*-1];
    b = [ones(TS,1)*(IntYInit-IntYMin);ones(TS,1)*(IntYMax-IntYInit)];
    lb = ones(TS,1)*YMax;
    ub = ones(TS,1)*YMin;

    Y0 = ones(TS)*IntYInit;
Y = fmincon(@(x) costFun(x, Prices),Y0,A,b,[],[],lb,ub);
IntY = cumsum(Y);

function cost = costFun(x, Prices)
cost = sum(x*Prices);

function P = PricesFun(TS)
    x = linspace(1,TS,TS);
    pi = 3.1415;
P = 2 + sin(x/TS*4*pi);
```

The code above is self contained, if you want to try, you have just to paste it in matlab and call the function:

```
[Y, IntY] = optTest();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial guess `Y0` is what defines the number of variables involved in the optimization.  You are inputting a TS x TS square matrix for `Y0`, which would require TS*TS linear constraints.  Given that you're using column vectors for `lb` and `ub`, I assume you meant to create `Y0` as a column vector as well, or `Y0 = ones(TS,1)*IntYInit;`